# Transaction not reflecting on the Paypal App Account

Tags: node.js, paypal

I am successfully making a [Platform Transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/) on my Platform. All transfers go as expected apart from the Platform Fees. They reflect on the Merchant Seller's side, as well as the Buyer's, but not on the Platform Account.

**Transaction details snapshot**

[image]

The **Partner Commission** of **-$9.33 USD** does not show on the Platform account. In fact this transaction does not reflect in any way. There is no way of telling that it ever happened at all from the Paypal Sandbox App Account.

What could it be that I am missing?

Thank you all in advance.

**CLIENT SIDE : index.html**

```
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8"/>

  <!-- Optimal rendering on mobile devices. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Optimal Internet Explorer compatibility -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

  <!-- Sample CSS styles for demo purposes. You can override these styles to match your web page's branding. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/css/cardfields.css"/>

  <!-- JavaScript SDK -->
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?components=buttons,hosted-fields&client-id=Ae4XWCzGDY24rKpazdCnRnT1wUjnQ_2PzLF5aOhviaUfQ7_O34rr8NqrunXe7PxCi-sEt7noZfr1ojbs" data-client-token="eyJicmFpbnRyZWUiOnsiYXV0aG9yaXphdGlvbkZpbmdlcnByaW50IjoiZWNkYWE1MzZjNjQ5Nzg1YjU2ZWQ5NGMyZGU2ZjRjMGQzY2FiMDY0MzkyNTA3YTkxZTU2MjI3MDlhZTMzOWUyNHxtZXJjaGFudF9pZD1yd3dua3FnMnhnNTZobTJuJnB1YmxpY19rZXk9NjNrdm4zN3Z0MjlxYjRkZiZjcmVhdGVkX2F0PTIwMjEtMDMtMjlUMTM6Mjg6MTMuOTQxWiIsInZlcnNpb24iOiIzLXBheXBhbCJ9LCJwYXlwYWwiOnsiaWRUb2tlbiI6ImV5SnJhV1FpT2lJNVpqWmxOalV5T0RGallXWmhORFU1WkRReU9EWmhPRE5pWVdZMVl6aGtPRFUwWVdNNE5XRmtJaXdpZEhsd0lqb2lTbGRVSWl3aVlXeG5Jam9pVWxNeU5UWWlmUS5leUpwYzNNaU9pSm9kSFJ3Y3pvdkwyRndhUzV6WVc1a1ltOTRMbkJoZVhCaGJDNWpiMjBpTENKemRXSWlPaUpvZEhSd2N6b3ZMM2QzZHk1d1lYbHdZV3d1WTI5dEwzZGxZbUZ3Y0hNdllYVjBhQzlwWkdWdWRHbDBlUzkxYzJWeUwwSlhRazEyZVhoclJsWjBkWHBCZUd4RmNGZENiMVJRTkhSNGFHOVRVMnh0YVZWWmNtbDZhM3BrWkdjaUxDSmhZM0lpT2xzaVkyeHBaVzUwSWwwc0ltRjFaQ0k2SWtGbE5GaFhRM3BIUkZreU5ISkxjR0Y2WkVOdVVtNVVNWGRWYW01Ulh6SlFla3hHTldGUGFIWnBZVlZtVVRkZlR6TTBjbkk0VG5GeWRXNVlaVGRRZUVOcExYTkZkRGR1YjFwbWNqRnZhbUp6SWl3aVlYVjBhRjkwYVcxbElqb3hOakUzTURJME5EazBMQ0poYlhJaU9sdGRMQ0poZWlJNkluTmlMbk5zWXlJc0ltVjRjQ0k2TVRZeE56QXlOVE01TkN3aWMyVnpjMmx2Ymw5cGJtUmxlQ0k2SWxoMVNuUnBiMDU0WWs1YU1HOVFUVzVpTWtkNVpXdHRRMWh3UXlJc0ltbGhkQ0k2TVRZeE56QXlORFE1TkN3aWFuUnBJam9pVlRKQlFVbGtiVVZETTJjekxVTkpOelpDYWtSdk56WjNUVFpoZDJ4VWJuWmFNMGhsVW5kWmNXRmxTazUyZW1SWFpWTmlhMUUyVERoUU5qbFdUako0Y21kR1prTkNUVGxHYVdGRGNVNHhSUzFqTVZobVEzSndZWFJPTWxGWVltczFZbE4yVlZveVpYTlRTRzU1VG1aaWRWUkxZamxQUjB0cWNGRjZSbWR5V0ZFaUxDSmpiR2xsYm5SZmFXUWlPaUpCWlRSWVYwTjZSMFJaTWpSeVMzQmhlbVJEYmxKdVZERjNWV3B1VVY4eVVIcE1SalZoVDJoMmFXRlZabEUzWDA4ek5ISnlPRTV4Y25WdVdHVTNVSGhEYVMxelJYUTNibTlhWm5JeGIycGljeUo5LkhObzlndU5SQVktSDZTR2tUR0xxRUFtbDNWRkJwNHRwNjdSSVJPN1NMbm5PRUtkWGFHSjhfYkJfR3N5dWxZeGQ4Slhnd3duTWV4ejZYaElEUnVtVzVkaDloQm9CbFctTGtNUEZ6cmVDZnk3SnVnbmZPYk9PaWRhV19Wd1IyRXpLSTZ1UzZWaFhKbEFvaWI1U3dfYjNXYlVHR2tudUM5cjZDZ0xlWnNTaDVQZDRuaFc1M0pplatformlHQTZkOVc3ZU5VZXBKNUJwd1FJWkRVYmJyY2JXelFDMzRFN0tQbndjOENIQWh3UGNSZWpWaktWWVlLSE9lUF9KeWpEbFZDWXM4NU5YVEExYV9ldDdFUHZmcmN1NzF0S3FhR0hNV21XWE9KS245UGZ2Zk10b2ZfRWN3SmhVd2RBU1ZqZmU4VjlzM3ZidzRJRGZHMFRjYzY1d2hIaFp4Sl94dyIsImFjY2Vzc1Rva2VuIjoiQTIxQUFJNTNiLVl0Qk1neFlmb1NQZHJKUUsxZTBCYVZSZm01X3BPNlg4bnktZ292S1l3dy11YU1fWm8wM0YxQXdzenZfYjF4RmZJTkE1YkNfUEZya3A0bkxxMzljdWdndyJ9fQ=="></script>
  
  <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Ae4XWCzGDY24rKpazdCnRnT1wUjnQ_2PzLF5aOhviaUfQ7_O34rr8NqrunXe7PxCi-sEt7noZfr1ojbs&currency=USD" data-namespace="paypal_sdk"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <!-- JavaScript SDK -->
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?components=hosted-fields&client-id=Ae4XWCzGDY24rKpazdCnRnT1wUjnQ_2PzLF5aOhviaUfQ7_O34rr8NqrunXe7PxCi-sEt7noZfr1ojbs&merchant-id=H82BJAGD75E6C&currency=USD&intent=capture" data-partner-attribution-id="FLAVORsb-z1ivv5077605_MP" data-client-token="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"></script>

  <!-- Buttons container -->
  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

  <!-- Implementation -->
  <script>
    let orderId;

      // Displays PayPal buttons
      paypal_sdk.Buttons({
        style: {
          layout: 'horizontal'
        },

        // Call your server to set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/platform_store_order/create/', {
            method: 'post'
          }).catch(error => {
            console.error('ERR -> fetch : ' + error.message);
          }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
          }).catch(error => {
            console.error('ERR -> res : ' + error.message);
          }).then(function(orderData) {
            return orderData.id;
          }).catch(error => {
            console.error('ERR -> orderData : ' + error.message);
          });
        },

        // Call your server to finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order_platform_store/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({'orderID': data.orderID, 'payerID': data.payerID})
          }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
          }).then(function(orderData) {
                // Three cases to handle:
                //   (1) Recoverable INSTRUMENT_DECLINED -> call actions.restart()
                //   (2) Other non-recoverable errors -> Show a failure message
                //   (3) Successful transaction -> Show confirmation or thank you

                // This example reads a v2/checkout/orders capture response, propagated from the server
                // You could use a different API or structure for your 'orderData'
                var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];

                if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                    return actions.restart(); // Recoverable state, per:
                    // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/
                  }

                  if (errorDetail) {
                    var msg = 'Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.';
                    
                    if (errorDetail.description) {
                      msg += '\n\n' + errorDetail.description;
                    }

                    if (orderData.debug_id){
                      msg += ' (' + orderData.debug_id + ')'
                    };

                    return alert(msg); // Show a failure message
                  }

                // Show a success message
                alert('Transaction : ' + JSON.stringify(orderData));
              });
        }
      }).render("#paypal-button-container");
    </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

**NODE app.js**

```
const path = require("path");

var express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");
var app = express();

var request = require("request");

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors());

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Add your credentials:
// Add your client ID and secret
var CLIENT = "Ae4XWCzGDY24rKpazdCnRnT1wUjnQ_2PzLF5aOhviaUfQ7_O34rr8NqrunXe7PxCi-sEt7noZfr1ojbs";
var SECRET = "EMmNF1LZSOooLUAxEt5csF-rMyIseuV5D6qOoKMzbyUEDaQEhO_DjLarbVsF_vLiXnGHi8qFL13gebg_";
var PAYPAL_API = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com";

const paypal = require("@paypal/checkout-server-sdk");

let environment = new paypal.core.SandboxEnvironment(CLIENT, SECRET);
let client = new paypal.core.PayPalHttpClient(environment);

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

// Set up the payment:
// 1. Set up a URL to handle requests from the PayPal button
app.post("/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/create/", async function (req, res) {
    let ordersCreateRequest = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
    ordersCreateRequest.requestBody({
        "intent": "CAPTURE",
        "purchase_units": [
            {
                "amount": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": "9.88",
                },
            },
        ],
    });

    // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
    let createOrder = async function () {
        let response = await client.execute(ordersCreateRequest);
        return response;
    };

    let platformOrder = await createOrder();
    let orderId = platformOrder.result.id;

    // 2. Call /v2/checkout/orders to set up the Order
    res.json({
        id: orderId,
    });
});

// Set up the payment:
// 1. Set up a URL to handle requests from the PayPal button
app.post("/demo/checkout/api/paypal/platform_store_order/create/", async function (req, res) {
    let ordersCreateRequest = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
    ordersCreateRequest.requestBody({
        "intent": "CAPTURE",
        "purchase_units": [
            {
                "amount": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": "31.13",
                },
                "payee": {
                    "email_address": "platform@business.example.com",
                },
                "payment_instruction": {
                    "disbursement_mode": "INSTANT",
                    "platform_fees": [
                        {
                            "amount": {
                                "currency_code": "USD",
                                "value": "9.33",
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
        ],
    });

    // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
    let createOrder = async function () {
        let response = await client.execute(ordersCreateRequest);
        return response;
    };

    let platformOrder = await createOrder();
    let orderId = platformOrder.result.id;

    res.json({
        id: orderId,
    });
});

// 1. Set up a URL to handle requests from the PayPal button.
app.post("/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order_platform_store/", async function (req, res) {
    // 2. Get the payment ID and the payer ID from the request query.
    var orderID = req.body.orderID;

    request.post(
        PAYPAL_API + "/v2/checkout/orders/" + orderID + "/capture",
        {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer A21AAJ8sH_Uq73w8XonQYB9rc1STsZpoK_Q14PkHbRgxtbYUN6FvCg-FbOKYIDlt0Zzo8xVQMvSuCAaRgjSfGoEPYRbxk62xQ",
                "PayPal-Partner-Attribution-Id": "FLAVORsb-z1ivv5077605_MP",
            },
        },
        function (err, response, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            }

            res.json(response);
        }
    );
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you a PayPal partner? It's required to use this in the live environment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/test-go-live/#2-go-live

If you are, PayPal will guide you in testing this in both sandbox and live modes.

If you are not, you can't use this anyway.

Comment: As you can see, I'm only testing it out on the Sandbox. `var PAYPAL_API = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com";` Is this still the case?